# How to query in Mongodb based on specific data?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have the following schemas in Mongodb:

Problem schema:

```
'use strict';

// modules dependencies
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// model
var ProblemSchema = new Schema({

  description: {
    type     : String,
    unique   : false,
    required : false
  },
  creator: {
    type     : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    unique   : false,
    required : true,
    ref      : 'User'
  },
  idea: {
    type     : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    unique   : false,
    required : true,
    ref      : 'Idea'
  }
});

mongoose.model('Problem', ProblemSchema);
```

And Idea schema:

```
'use strict';

// modules dependencies
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

// model
var IdeaSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type     : String,
    unique   : true,
    required : true
  },
  description: {
    type     : String,
    unique   : false,
    required : false
  },
  creator: {
    type     : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    unique   : false,
    required : true,
    ref      : 'User'
  },
  image : String
});

mongoose.model('Idea', IdeaSchema);
```

In the backed I have the following :

```
exports.getById = function (req, res) {
     Problem.findById({idea:req.params.id}, function (err, problem) {
        if (err) return res.status(400).send(err)

        if (problem) {
          res.send(problem);
        } else {
          res.status(404).send('Problem not found')
        }
      });
    };
```

I am trying to query for Problems based on Idea id,but this is not working ,and I am getting the following error:
GET http://localhost:3001/api/problems/5698ee90d62061f40bb00a7d 400 (Bad Request)
I am new to angularjs and nodejs,hope any one can help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Try using findOne instead of findById?

```
exports.getById = function (req, res) {
 Problem.findOne({idea:req.params.id}, function (err, problem) {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err)

    if (problem) {
      res.send(problem);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Problem not found')
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [`findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) means Finds a single document by its _id field. findById(id) is almost equivalent to `findOne({ _id: id })`. replace it with `findOne` as following

```
exports.getById = function (req, res) {
 Problem.findOne({idea:req.params.id}, function (err, problem) {
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err)

    if (problem) {
      res.send(problem);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Problem not found')
    }
  });
};
```